# Customizing Field Layout / UI element in Craft Control Panel

Tags: templating, control-panel

Maybe I don't understand well the usage of UI Element in Field Layout, but I would like to display something more 'jazzy' for the admin on his CP and I thought inserting a twig template in the page would be nice. But within the twig, I don't see how I could get the field data of the actual entry on page. I don't find any documentation on this feature and how to use it.
Can you shed lights on this please ?
Say here I want to use those value in twig.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The template will be rendered with an `element` variable which you can use to display fields and other properties of the given element. See the info displayed in the settings once you add it to the field layout:

[image: Screenshot of the UI element "template" settings]

In general, here's useful debugging method to find out what variables are available in a given template:

```twig
{% dd _context | keys %}
```

The `_context` variable contains all variables available in the current scope. Dumping the entire `_context` is quite unwieldy, so you can use the `keys` filter to only show the variable names.

Comment: Thanks a lot @MoritzLost that's all I needed ! 
So it all start with  _context variable, it's good to know ! 

Thanks again, I can going on from this !